# How can I zip a file from ftp and transferer to another in PHP?

Tags: php

I do have access to ssh, so I would like to know how can I connect to a ftp then make a zip file then transferer to another ftp?

Is there any script that does it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it using FTP.

But ofcourse you can do it using ssh.

First login to your server using ssh

```
ssh -l username hostname
```

It will ask for the password. Enter the password and go to the directory where your directory resides.

then execute the command

```
zip -r yourzipfilename.zip directoryname
```

It will create the zip file and now you can send it to another ftp using `ftp` command.

Comment: I dont have access to ssh, like I said. ): I want to do it with php.

Comment: Use `exec('ssh -l username hostname');` in PHP code.

Comment: how can I type the password with exec?

Comment: Run [this](https://www.exratione.com/2014/08/bash-script-ssh-automation-without-a-password-prompt/) shell script to avoid the problem of password prompt.

Comment: I cant run this script on php. Can u provide to me an example? please

Comment: yes of course you can, just use above command as `exec(bash script.sh);`

Comment: Thanks, but Im trying to find how can I do it with php because Im building a system in php, and this systems needs to use php for doing that.

Comment: exec is a php function as you can see

Comment: Yes , I know, I cant create a script.sh on the remote server, that is the real problem. I cant modify the remove server ):

Comment: Thais why I was trying to transfer by ftp functions.

Comment: Ok.Thanks anyway for your attention .

Comment: no problem, I always try to help some cases I had been succeeded but not every time it's possible.